# Javascript - Ajax adds extra commas in JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

i'm trying to perform a request to a RESTful server by the HTTP Node.js module.

Since the response is quite huge (64 chunks, around 100kb), the HTTP module merges the chunks into a single string response in this way:

```
   res.setEncoding('utf8');

   res.on('data', (chunk) => {
     index ++;
     body.push(chunk);
   });

   res.on('end', () => {
     console.log("===> CHUNKS COUNTER: ".red+index);
   }
```

But despite this "default" approach, the body content has few misplaces commas, like this:

```
}},{"ty,pe"
```

insted of be:

```
}},{"type"
```

is there anyone who can help me? Thanks in advace!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't push chunks to the body. Chunks are strings, just concatenate them.

```
body += chunk
```

Then parse your full string to JSON :

```
JSON.parse(body)
```

Comment: Wow, i didn't think that a mistake like that could generate this errors!
I solved with your help! Thanks a lot!
Thanks also to Yury for his answer btw.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `body` is an array. If you want to convert it to a string w/o commas use `body = body.join('')`.

```
res.on('end', () => {
  body = body.join('')
  console.log("===> CHUNKS COUNTER: ".red+index);
 }
```